# How to write the ZF2 router script to allow parameters on the default action

Tags: routes, zend-framework2, url-routing

I am trying to get around some of the idiosyncrasies of the routing statements in ZF2.  The Album module example suggests the following:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Let’s say, however, that I wanted to configure the project so that the url, `/album/index/jazz` would list only the albums in the jazz genre.

My first challenge is that in `/album/index/jazz` the second argument is not `[/:id]`.  It wants to be `[/:genre]`.  And, while I could easily just change the route to `'route'  => '/album[/:action][/:arg1]'`, and the constraint to `'arg1' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'`, I don’t really want to give up the `'[0-9]+'`, constraint on the id.  What I’m looking for is a way to define alternative parameter patterns and constraints depending upon what the action is.

My second challenge lies in ZF2’s treatment of the default action.  If I set up the routing as follows:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:arg1]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'arg1'   => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

then the url `/album/index/jazz` will send the “jazz” argument to the controller as I want it to.  However, I have a problem getting ZF2 to construct the url using the default action.  Following the syntax from the `index.phtml` in the Album module example, my expectation is that the following:

```
    <a href="<?php echo $this->url('album',
        array('action'=>'index', 'agr1' => 'jazz'));?>">Jazz</a>
```

would construct `<a href="/album/index/jazz "> Jazz </a>`.  But (I assume because index is the default action) index gets stripped out and ZF2 gives `<a href="/album/jazz ">Jazz</a>`, which doesn’t target a real page.  I’ve tried renaming `index` to something different in the router, the controller and the view; but have found that as long as it’s the default action, the `$this->url( … )` function will strip out whatever name I use.  There are probably a number of ways around this issue, but I think it’s best to solve it in the router configuration to avoid surprises with other unknown parts of the framework that may treat the default action similarly.

Comment: Have you defined any other routes? The url you expect to generate doesn't relate to the route definition you provided -- path starts with `/pages` whereas, based upon that `album` route definition, it should start with `/album`.

Comment: My bad.  I cut and pasted from different versions of my project.  I've edited my question.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I've either had to remove the default action, or stop letting ZF construct the urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to work around the issue that the default parameters get left out of the url that the `url()` helper configures.  When zf2 develops the url from the route statements, it drops out everything within the `[]` brackets that match the default parameters.  Therefore,

```
    <a href="<?php echo $this->url('album',
        array('action'=>'index', 'arg1' => 'jazz'));?>">Jazz</a>
```

constructs `<a href="/album/jazz">Jazz</a>` instead `<a href="/album/index/jazz">Jazz</a>` of when the route statement includes `'route' => '/album[/:action][/:arg1]',` as I presented in the question.  However, if I breakout the `/` character from the parameter(s) and give it it's own`[]` brackets, the `url()` helper only drops the `:action` part of the url.  In other words, if I replace

```
                'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:arg1]',
```

with

```
                'route'    => '/album[/][:action][/][:arg1]',
```

then

```
    <a href="<?php echo $this->url('album',
        array('action'=>'index', 'arg1' => 'jazz'));?>">Jazz</a>
```

constructs `<a href="/album//jazz ">Jazz</a>`, which points to the page it should.

---

*I also got a lot out of [timdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172588/timdev)'s answer, "It's worth it to take a step back and decide how you want your url scheme to work, and then figure out how to implement it."  If I want to add a whole lot of bells and whistles to how I want to query, filter and sort the data, the`index` action (which manages multiple albums) is going to want to take a completely different set of parameters than the `add`, `edit` and `delete` actions (which each only manage a single album at a time.)  So I set up two routes:*

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'albums' => array(
            ...
                'route'    => '/albums[/][:action] [/][:arg1] [/][:arg2] [/][:arg3]   ...  ',
            ...
        ),
        'album' => array(
            ...
                'route'    => '/album[/][:action][/][:id]',
            ...
        ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worth it to take a step back and decide how you want you url scheme to work, and then figure out how to implement it.

If I were doing something similar, I'd might start like:

/albums[/:category] - lists all albums, optionally filtered by category

/albums/:id - display info about a single album

/albums/:id/edit - display a form to edit an album's information, and accept POST

/albums/:id/delete - POST only, deletes an album

/albums/new - Display form for adding an album, and accept POST.

I would advise against having general-purpose nouns in your routes (so, avoid :action, or :arg1).  Instead, be explicit, and everything usually just works.

For the first go-around, just specify each route explicitly.  Once you've got your head around that, you can start looking into using child routes to group them together.