# Route with name "HelloWorld" not found Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have created a new module in ZF2 named 'HelloWorld'. What I am trying to do is, simply printing HelloWorld when I click on the link 'HelloWorld': 
[image]

I want to generate this [link](http://mayukh.my.phpcloud.com/zf2test/HelloWorld/)(http://mayukh.my.phpcloud.com/zf2test/HelloWorld/) by using this:

```
$this->url('HelloWorld', array('action' => 'index'))
```

But it is showing the error like this:
http://mayukh.my.phpcloud.com/zf2test/

Please suggest how to avoid this error..

Comment: There is a custom, when you vote -ve, you just explain a little... 'why'?

Comment: You're trying to output a link to the `HelloWorld` route, the error is telling you that no such route exists. Routes are defined in your module config. Perhaps if you could tell us what steps you took to create your http://mayukh.my.phpcloud.com/zf2test/HelloWorld/ page (did you create a controller or add a new action?) we might be able to advise further.

Comment: Yes, I have created HelloWorldController and indexAction is written insdie. This link works: http://mayukh.my.phpcloud.com/zf2test/HelloWorld/

Comment: But, I just can not create this link with this:$this->url('HelloWorld', array('action' => 'index'))

Comment: only problem is generating the link. If I try to add the link inside application/view/layout/layout.phtml it shows a blank page. Is it because I created a new module HelloWorld? Thats why I tried to print the link inside: Application/view/application/index/index.phtml and currently getting this error...

Comment: Did you add or change the routes in `modules/Application/config/module.config.php`?

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps related to one of ZF2’s “features.”   It seems that if you use ZF2 functions to construct your links, the function will drop out any segment that matches the default value you have named in your router script.  See [How to write the ZF2 router script to allow parameters on the default action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565216).

Temporarily change or remove the defaults from your router script and see if that doesn’t solve your issue.  If it does, you might have to either reconsider the scheme for your router scripts or code your links without ZF2’s url function.